# Send mail but just when wordpress post is updatet

Tags: wordpress

I use

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

to send an email when a post is updated. But save_post is also firing when a post is created. How can i just run this function when i update an existing post?

Comment: `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated

Comment: `post_updated` ?  see more https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134667/15420

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    function check_post_data_changes($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
    echo 'Post ID:';
    var_dump($post_ID);

    echo 'Post Object AFTER update:';
    var_dump($post_after);

    echo 'Post Object BEFORE update:';
    var_dump($post_before);

}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_post_data_changes', 10, 3 );
```

Here you can check various field in `post_after` and `post_before` like `post_name` or `post_date_gmt` to know whether it is new post or edited post

Comment: Thank you. This solution is sending a message when a new post is saved / published the first time. I need a solution where just a mail is sent when i update a post.